# Are there any viewers for ImageMarker?

Tags: ros, marker, visualization-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've noticed an ImageMarker message type in visualization_msgs. However in searching for ImageMarker in all my installed stacks and via google, I've found no reference to any package using it anywhere.

Is there some viewer that uses this? Has it been superseded by something else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11982/are-there-any-viewers-for-imagemarker?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-11-17

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There aren't. In fact, `rosmsg users visualization_msgs/ImageMarker` comes up completely dry.

The problem with `ImageMarker` is that there's a very simple alternative: just draw your markers/annotations on the input image, publish that as a new topic, and watch in `image_view`. Why use `ImageMarker` then?

Pros:

- Maybe you save bandwidth if you need both the original and marked-up images.

Cons:

- You get a very limited set of operations.
- It's cumbersome. If I want to draw circles around a bunch of feature points in an image, it's actually more work to publish a bunch of `ImageMarker`s than to use `cv::circle()`.
- Now you have synchronization issues between the marker and image messages.

So, I don't see the use case. You add complexity without gaining a whole lot. Probably `ImageMarker` was a bad idea from the beginning.

By contrast, `visualization_msgs/Marker` is useful because it lets you talk to `rviz`, and because it describes the world. `Marker` can be understood on its own. `rviz` integrates data about the world from an arbitrary number of sources, so a `Marker` topic is just one more channel. Whereas an `ImageMarker` is useless without the source image, so why separate the two?

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-11-18**:
I see utility in much the same way Marker is (if there was a viewer). These plenty of case for being able to turn on and off marker layers IMO. There's a good case for ImageMarker where the original image is processed into several forms (HSV, edge, etc) and especially were by several separate nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I work on an app called Foxglove Studio that supports ImageMarkers. Check it out at: https://foxglove.dev/blog/annotate-your-robots-camera-images-with-image-markers

(It was originally based on the [Webviz](https://discourse.ros.org/t/webviz-ros-data-visualization-in-the-browser/9783) project from Cruise.)

To publish multiple markers at once, you can use [foxglove_msgs/ImageMarkerArray](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/foxglove_msgs/html/msg/ImageMarkerArray.html).

---

Originally posted by [jtbandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/28561/jtbandes/) with karma: 33 on 2019-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3